# Fastest way to find the nearest pairs between two numpy arrays without duplicates

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, distance

Given two large numpy arrays `A` and `B` with different number of rows (`len(B) > len(A)`) but same number of columns (`A.shape[1] = B.shape[1] = 3`). I want to know the fastest way to get a subset `C` from `B` that has the minimum **total** distance (sum of all pair-wise distances) to `A` **without duplicates** (each pair must be both unique). This means `C` should have the same shape as `A`.

Below is my code, but there are two main issues:

1. I cannot tell if this gives the minimum **total** distance
2. In reality I have a much more expensive distance-calculating function rather than `np.linalg.norm` (needs to take care of periodic boundary conditions). I think this is definitely not the fastest way to go since the code below calls the distance-calculating function one pair per time. There is a significant overhead when I call the more expensive distance-calculating function and it will run forever. Any suggestions?

```
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter
import random
import time

A = 100.*np.random.rand(1000, 3)
B = A.copy()
for (i,j), _ in np.ndenumerate(B):
    B[i,j] += np.random.rand()
B = np.vstack([B, 100.*np.random.rand(500, 3)])

def calc_dist(x, y):
    return np.linalg.norm(x - y)

t0 = time.time()
taken = []
for rowi in A:
    res = min(((k, calc_dist(rowi, rowj)) for k, rowj in enumerate(B)
                if k not in taken), key=itemgetter(1))
    taken.append(res[0])

C = B[taken]

print(A.shape, B.shape, C.shape)
>>> (1000, 3) (1500, 3) (1000, 3)

print(time.time() - t0)
>>> 12.406389951705933
```

Edit: for those who are interested in the expensive distance-calculating function, it uses the `ase` package (can be installed by `pip install ase`)

```
from ase.geometry import find_mic
def calc_mic_dist(x, y):
    return find_mic(np.array([x]) - np.array([y]), 
                    cell=np.array([[50., 0.0, 0.0], 
                                   [25., 45., 0.0], 
                                   [0.0, 0.0, 100.]]))[1][0]
```

Comment: Perhaps you could vectorize the computation of the function, can you describe it?

Comment: I add the expensive distance-calculating function.

Comment: Just a thought, how about sorting `A` and `B` arrays and start considering elements in `B` for subset `C` from the `n`th element in `B`  which is closest to the first element in `A`? (additional detail: if the value of `n` is more than `len(B) - len(A)` then the `n` can be shifted backwards as a compromise) I think this way would generate the best pairs and ensure the smallest distance. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes I do agree that A and B should be first sorted in some way so that each pair are always the "perfect" pair, but I don't quite understand the shift backwads part. It would be more understandable if you can write some pseudocode.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem#Unbalanced_assignment

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're OK with calculating the whole N² distances, which isn't that expensive for the sizes you've given, `scipy.optimize` has a function that will solve this directly.

```
import scipy.optimize
cost = np.linalg.norm(A[:, np.newaxis, :] - B, axis=2)
_, indexes = scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment(cost)
C = B[indexes]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the power of numpy broadcasting and vectorization

`find_mic` method in `ase.geometry` can handle 2d np arrays.

```
from ase.geometry import find_mic
def calc_mic_dist(x, y):
    return find_mic(x - y, 
                    cell=np.array([[50., 0.0, 0.0], 
                                   [25., 45., 0.0], 
                                   [0.0, 0.0, 100.]]))[1]
```

Test:

```
x = np.random.randn(1,3)
y = np.random.randn(5,3)

print (calc_mic_dist(x,y).shape)
# It is a distance metrics so:
assert np.allclose(calc_mic_dist(x,y), calc_mic_dist(y,x))
```

Ouptput:

```
(5,)
```

As you can see the metrics is calculated for each value of `x` with each value of `y`, because `x-y` in numpy does the magic of broadcasting.

#### Solution:

```
def calc_mic_dist(x, y):
    return find_mic(x - y, 
                    cell=np.array([[50., 0.0, 0.0], 
                                   [25., 45., 0.0], 
                                   [0.0, 0.0, 100.]]))[1]

t0 = time.time()
A = 100.*np.random.rand(1000, 3)
B = 100.*np.random.rand(5000, 3)
selected = [np.argmin(calc_mic_dist(a, B)) for a in A]
C = B[selected]
print (A.shape, B.shape, C.shape)

print (f"Time: {time.time()-t0}")
```

Output:

```
(1000, 3) (5000, 3) (1000, 3)
Time: 9.817562341690063
```

Takes around 10secs on google collab

#### Testing:

We know that `calc_mic_dist(x,x)` == `0` so If `A` is a subset of `B` then `C` should exactly be `A`

```
A = 100.*np.random.rand(1000, 3)
B = np.vstack([100.*np.random.rand(500, 3), A, 100.*np.random.rand(500, 3)])
selected = [np.argmin(calc_mic_dist(a, B)) for a in A]
C = B[selected]
print (A.shape, B.shape, C.shape)
print (np.allclose(A,C))
```

Output:

```
(1000, 3) (2000, 3) (1000, 3)
True
```

#### Edit 1: Avoid duplicates

> Once a vector in `B` is selected it cannot be again selected for other
> values of  `A`

This can be achieved by remove the selected vector from `B` once it is selected so that it does not appear again for next rows of `A` as a possible candidate.

```
A = 100.*np.random.rand(1000, 3)
B = np.vstack([100.*np.random.rand(500, 3), A, 100.*np.random.rand(500, 3)])

B_ = B.copy()
C = np.zeros_like(A)

for i, a in enumerate(A):
  s = np.argmin(calc_mic_dist(a, B_))
  C[i] = B_[s]
  # Remove the paried 
  B_ = np.delete(B_, (s), axis=0)

print (A.shape, B.shape, C.shape)
print (np.allclose(A,C))
```

Output:

```
(1000, 3) (2000, 3) (1000, 3)
True
```

Comment: The numpy broadcasting is good, but your code will generate duplicates. For example, one point in ```A``` can be the nearest point to multiple points in ```B```, but what I want to achieve is, once the point in ```A``` is paired, it can no longer be paired again.

Comment: @ShaunHan Hope the edit will suffice your requirement.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is close but still not exactly what I want because this cannot ensure a minimum total distance. I think ```A``` and ```B``` should be first sorted in some kind of way so that each pair is a "perfect" pair.