# Loosen scipy.optimize problem and accelerate solution

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have two sets of coordinates, `pos1.txt` and `pos2.txt` (attached).
The ID of the points correspond to the line numbers.
I want to find a set of indices to apply to the first set to approach as much as possible the second one, while keeping the first positions.
`scipy.optimize` seems to do a great job at this, and below is the code I am using so far.

However, I would like to "loosen" the optimization problem since it is too slow for my purpose (ideally, I would use 500,000 points), and I do not really know how to proceed:

1. The most important parts to match are z and r, by far. I do not
   really care if the position is drastically different in `[x, y]`, as
   long as the radial distance and z are the same.
2. The positions for `z/zmax>90%` can be completely interchangeable. If a point in this zone
   changes its radial position a lot or its z (while staying in the >90%), it is okay.

I attached the current plot of the ID and errors, and we can see that the radial/axial distances can differ by up to 7% in the whole geometry, which is higher than my target, while it is pretty slow.

Would anybody have hints on what to do, and how to decrease the time?

Here is the code:

```
import scipy.optimize
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

# First set of points with random order
list1 = np.genfromtxt('pos1.txt', delimiter=',')
ax = fig.add_subplot(231, projection="3d")
s = ax.scatter3D(list1[:,0], list1[:,1], list1[:,2], c=np.arange(list1.shape[0]), cmap='jet', s=5)
plt.colorbar(s)
plt.title('ID1')

# Second set of points, sorted and different positions
list2 = np.genfromtxt('pos2.txt', delimiter=',')
ax = fig.add_subplot(232, projection="3d")
s = ax.scatter3D(list2[:,0], list2[:,1], list2[:,2], c=np.arange(list2.shape[0]), cmap='jet', s=5)
plt.colorbar(s)
plt.title('ID2')

# Calculate third set of points
# With scipy.optimize which indices to apply on first set to have lowest distance to second set
cost = np.linalg.norm(list2[:, np.newaxis, :] - list1, axis=2)
_, indices = scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment(cost)
list3 = list1[indices]
ax = fig.add_subplot(233, projection="3d")
list2 = np.genfromtxt('pos2.txt', delimiter=',')
s = ax.scatter3D(list3[:,0], list3[:,1], list3[:,2], c=np.arange(list3.shape[0]), cmap='jet', s=5)
plt.colorbar(s)
plt.title('ID3')

# Calculate error made on distance, radial distance, axial distance
error_dist = np.linalg.norm(list2-list3, axis=1)/np.max(cost)*100
ax = fig.add_subplot(234, projection="3d")
list2 = np.genfromtxt('pos2.txt', delimiter=',')
s = ax.scatter3D(list3[:,0], list3[:,1], list3[:,2], c=error_dist, cmap='jet', s=5)
plt.colorbar(s)
plt.title('Error on distance (%)')

r_dist2 = np.linalg.norm(list2[:, :2], axis=1)
r_dist3 = np.linalg.norm(list3[:, :2], axis=1)
error_r_dist = (r_dist3-r_dist2)/np.max(r_dist2)*100
ax = fig.add_subplot(235, projection="3d")
list2 = np.genfromtxt('pos2.txt', delimiter=',')
s = ax.scatter3D(list3[:,0], list3[:,1], list3[:,2], c=error_r_dist, cmap='jet', s=5)
plt.colorbar(s)
plt.title('Error on radial distance (%)')

error_z_dist = (list3[:,2]-list2[:,2])/(np.max(list3[:,2])-np.min(list3[:,2]))*100
ax = fig.add_subplot(236, projection="3d")
list2 = np.genfromtxt('pos2.txt', delimiter=',')
s = ax.scatter3D(list3[:,0], list3[:,1], list3[:,2], c=error_z_dist, cmap='jet', s=5)
plt.colorbar(s)
plt.title('Error on axial distance (%)')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('match_pos.png', dpi=600)
plt.show()
```

I uploaded the position files on this website:

- pos1.txt: https://zerobin.net/?1be6d4810e148e20#qflDwnHeACHuWzZKrtFdTxukdsvNSrWK+2cJ9l3XWLQ=
- pos2.txt: https://zerobin.net/?ecc23876cd7190e7#9e2AKTWp/mSXjlqEZavwEeslQ5oipN5gM+v3Xp4U1ws=

Thanks!

[image: Plots of positions and errors made]

Comment: I tried to change the cost function by creating a two-column array `rz` for each list. The first column corresponds to the radial distance, and the second corresponds to the `z` element of each coordinate. The cost looks like that: 
`cost = np.linalg.norm(rz2[:, np.newaxis, :] - rz1, axis=2)`. It helps to get lower errors (maximum of 3% radial and axial error), but the time is the exact same, even if the third element of the shape of the ´cost´ array becomes 2 instead of 3. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373827/fastest-way-to-find-the-nearest-pairs-between-two-numpy-arrays-without-duplicate), which details how to use ase.geometry to calculate distances "faster". However, the following code took 3min14s to complete, versus 47s to complete the numpy.linalg.norm way with my ~15,000 points. Is there something wrong with my implementation?

```
from ase.geometry import find_mic
def calc_mic_dist(x, y):
    return find_mic(x - y, cell=[[50., 0.0, 0.0], [25., 45., 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 100.]])[1]

list2_ = list2.copy()
list3 = np.zeros_like(list1)
for i, a in enumerate(list1):
  s = np.argmin(calc_mic_dist(a, list2_))
  list3 [i] = list2_[s]
  # Remove the paried 
  list2_ = np.delete(list2_, (s), axis=0)
```